# Is it possible to add a multiple value parameter query in SSRS with left()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder, ssrs-2019

I have a query in SSRS where I can search for a title with a certain prefix. The reason why I used left() is because there are some prefixes that have an underscore or a dash so I need my search results to be exact and it wasn't giving me that when I used the like operator.

Here's an example of what my query looks like:

```
select title
from table1
where left(title, len(@prefix)) = @prefix
```

This works if my prefix dropdown doesn't allow multiple values. Now, I have also tried this query:

```
select title
from table1
where left(title, len(@prefix)) in (@prefix)
```

But this just caused my report to generate a "Query execution failed for dataset" however, this query does work when I try it on SQL Server and when it isn't allowed for multiple values.

Comment: I ***hate*** that SSRS allows `IN (@Parameter)` syntax as it teaches people that syntax like the above will work, when it won't because SSRS is hiding what it's actually doing: injection. You'd be better off using an procedure here and having SSRS passing a delimited list (because it's dumb and still doesn't support TVPs....) and then handle the logic, and splitting, in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, I *hate* that SSRS allows the syntax `IN (@Parameter)`; it causes misunderstandings and teaches people incorrect syntax.

When you have statement like `SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE MyColumn IN (@MyParameter);` the SQL that SSRS runs is ***not*** that statement. Instead SSRS *removes* the parameter and then *injects* the multiple values into the statement. So the statement it *actually* runs would be something like `SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE MyColumn IN (N'MyValue1',N'MyValue2',N'MyValue3');`

If you were to actually run the SQL `SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE MyColumn IN (@MyParameter);` in SSMS, or *any other product*, it would be a synonym of `SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE MyColumn = @MyParameter;`. The syntax that SSRS uses is, for all intensive purposes, **wrong**.

There are *multiple* problems with that, which I'm not going to cover here.

When you then have a query like you do `LEFT(title, LEN(@prefix)) IN (@prefix)` you end up with a problem; `LEN(@prefix)` *can't* have tuples injected into it (`LEN(N'MyValue1',N'MyValue2',N'MyValue3')` isn't valid syntax). This just results in a invalid query because SSRS teaches bad habits.

The solution to this is th force SSRS to not be (completely) dumb. Unfortunately SSRS *is* dumb and *still* (even in SSRS 2022!) doesn't support Table Table Parameters (TVPs) which would *trivialise* this. As such you'll need to have SSRS pass a delimited value to a Procedure, and then you can handle the logic in your procedure. As you're using SSRS 2019 then you're also using SQL Server 2019 and thus have access to `STRING_SPLIT`. Also we can switch to a `LIKE` here.

This means you need a procedure like the following:

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.YourProc @prefix nvarchar(4000) --Assumed data type
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT title
    FROM dbo.table1 t1
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM STRING_SPLIT(@prefix,',') SS
                  WHERE t1.title LIKE SS.value + '%');
END;
```

Then, instead, you execute the procedure from your report.